# Listview with column and 2 buttons - set width to the largest one?

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` with a `Column`, and inside that `Column` 2 buttons.

The `ListView` is stretched to the entire page (it contains more elements)

I want all the buttons inside the `Column` to stretch to the button with the largest width.
I found a solution on usnig `InstrictWidth`, but when used inside a `Listview` I'm getting the error

```
LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
```

How can I still achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you can post your code, there are higher chances of getting assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each button with an Expanded widget and then wrap each one of these Expanded widgets with a Row widget

Comment: It doesn't work. It makes the button stretch to the width of the listview/page rather than be limited to the maximum-width button

Comment: So try Flexible instead of Expanded

Comment: doesn't work with Flexible either. Flexible won't make the buttons stretch, but it's just the same as not using it at all. That is, each button get it's own size regardless of the other buttons.